# Protbuf-net: what is the deference between ProtoMemberAttribute.AsReference and ProtoContract.AsReferenceDefault

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

What is the difference between `ProtoContract` property - `AsReferenceDefault`  and `ProtoMemberAttribute` property `AsReference`.

as per [wiki](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes):

> `AsReference` - enables reference tracking of the sub-object; this uses
>   a very different serialization layout, but will only serialize that
>   object once (giving it a unique token for referencing). This allows
>   full-graph support for otherwise cyclic graphs. This can also be used
>   to great effect to efficiently store common strings that are otherwise
>   repeated many times in the data

but how does it relate to `ProtoContract` property: `AsReferenceDefault`?

For instance, if set `AsReferenceDefault` to true does it mean that `ProtoMemberAttribute` property `AsReference`is no longer needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if `AsReferenceDefault` is applied to class, it will always serialize as reference even if corresponding property has not declared `AsReference` on `ProtoMemberAttribute`.

Ideally for your big class, you are sure that the object is big and it is better to serialize it once as reference, so you can mark it as `AsReferenceDefault`.

`AsReference` is designed to handle reference serialization even if it is not your own class, such as `String`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought in this way, but in our code, there are many cycles references, so `AsReferenceDefault` should handle it, but unfortunately, it did not, but after adding `AsReference` it works (for instance AsReference was set to `true` for `List<MyEntity>` but `MyEntity` already had it). So looks like there are some differences and I'm not sure what

Comment: No, List<MyEntity> would not work `AsReferenceDefault` even if `MyEntity` is `AsReferenceDefault`, If you have a class `MyEntityList : List<MyEntity>` and you can mark `MyEntityList` as `AsReferenceDefault`

Comment: yeah, but it does, without adding `AsReference = true` on the property `List<MyEntity>` I've got an exception (recursion was detected). Currently, I've `StackOverflow exception` and as per call stack protobuf tries to serialize the same objects (the data has cycles references), but at the same time `AsReferenceDefault = true`. I'm a bit curious about `AsReference` behavior, it's a bit unexpected

Comment: Can you try creating class `MyEntityList` and replace `List<MyEntity>` with `MyEntityList` and you get same exception?

Comment: I've checked with sample, yes you are right, thanks a lot